# What is the correct way to do an infinite loop that calls a method in Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a page that I want to update non stop, every few seconds.

For this, I wrote the following:

```
var to;
$(function () {
           to = setTimeout(updateDivContent, 2000);
});

function updateDivContent() {

    $('#topbox').load('/home/blabla', null);


    $('#leftgraph').load('/home/blabla', null, function () {

        to = setTimeout(updateDivContent, 2000);
    });
};
```

This worked, however, it leads to what I presume is a memory leak as after around 15 minutes, the computer almost freezes up with the browser taking up all available memory and CPU.

I am guessing that the Timeout is basically stacking, but, I am not sure how to fix this. I have tried getting rid of the second timeout and putting the first one inside a `while(true)` loop, but, I just couldn't get it to work.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: What you're already doing looks fine to me - you definitely do _not_ want a `while(true)` or similar. Does it still crash if you take the Ajax `.load()` calls out? (I know you obviously need them, but just for testing purposes...)

Comment: have you tried clearing the timeout with `clearTimeout` before you set a new timeout?

Comment: @WickyNilliams - there's nothing to clear: the previous one has already executed before the new one gets set.

Comment: Ignore me then :) I think i was confusing `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` with `setInterval`/`clearInterval`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks fine actually. But if the first Ajax call does not finish within two seconds, it will stack, and this *could* (don't know for sure) cause problems.

The timeout itself does not stack, since you are initiating a new one only after the previous one finished.

Try to initiate a new timeout once *both* Ajax requests finished:

```
$.when($('#topbox').load('/home/blabla'),
       $('#leftgraph').load('/home/blabla')
).then(function () {
    setTimeout(updateDivContent, 2000);
});
```

**Reference:** [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: As far as I am aware, the Ajax should be finishing, it is coming off of the lan and is typically instant... If you are interested... this is what is happening - http://i.imgur.com/YmLMf.png ... I will try your changes.... I am just curious about the .load - will it completely replace/get rid of the item it is replacing? The "blabla" is a highcharts chart, and, I am wondering if it is being disposed/unloaded or stays in memory/similar.... only conclusion I can think of.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any information about the context or the content of the page you load ;) But yeah, if `/home/blabla` is JavaScript which creates global variables, then those will continue to exist, until they are overwritten or deleted. I think it's difficult to give any proper suggestion here, it would require a more detailed analysis of the code.

Comment: no worries and have +1'ed this! I'll take out the updating of the charts and see what happens.

Comment: No need to up-vote if it does not help ;) Maybe your question is just not solvable through SO.

Comment: @wil have you considered doing some javascript profiling with chrome?

Comment: @WickyNilliams This really isn't my specialty at all :/ ... The problem is, I need to redraw the chart without flicker... doing .load() works fine, but, seems to cause this problems... tried a few other methods such as calling .empty() first seem to cause a flicker... just not sure of a better way of doing this, but, I may try to ask another question soon on it.

Comment: @wil: Do you mean it is the same chart but with different data? You can just update the existing chart and Highcharts even provides nice animations. Have a look at their documentation, this is probably what you should be doing.

Comment: @FelixKling Yep, it is the same chart - I have isolated just the script that Highcharts takes and have a MVC method that generates it - by using the .load(), I basically replace that script element... it does appear to work - just didn't realise that it was responsible for this memory leak - but, it makes sense.

Comment: Well, I am happy to upvote and will mark as answer... thanks for saying what I did was correct, and for giving the better code. from my limited understanding of the Chrome tools, I believe that it is Highcharts that are responsible - http://imgur.com/fJutH and I just have to find a better way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeOut`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval).

Comment: Normally I'd agree but there's an asyncronous HTTP request in play here too, which may take longer than your interval to return the response.

Comment: `setInterval` is worse, because the timing of the Ajax `.load()` function is variable. Better to use `setTimeout` in the complete callback of the `.load()` as already shown.

Comment: Then is't it better to do the next call in the OnComplete-event of the AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `clearTimeout` to invalidate the previous timer, like this:

```
clearTimeout(to);
to = setTimeout(updateDivContent, 2000);
```

Comment: I dont't think it's necessary, `to` gets overriden anyway on every `setTimeout`-Call.

Comment: Calling `clearTimeout()` on a timeout that has already occurred has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

can you this it will call ever 2 second

```
to = setInterval("updateDivContent", 2000);


function updateDivContent() {

$('#topbox').load('/home/blabla', null);


$('#leftgraph').load('/home/blabla', null, function () {

    //to = setTimeout(updateDivContent, 2000); 
});
};
```

Comment: `setInterval` is worse, because the timing of the Ajax `.load()` function is variable. Better to use `setTimeout` in the complete callback of the `.load()` as already shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setInterval`:

```
var to;

$(function () {
    to = setInterval(updateDivContent, 2000);
});

function updateDivContent() {
    $('#topbox').load('/home/blabla', null);
    $('#leftgraph').load('/home/blabla')
};
```